# How is it correct to use? Present Perfect and Past Simple

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

When do we use *past simple* and when do we use *present perfect* tense?

In the following example:

> Who has created this building?

I think I must use *present perfect* because I don't have any hint which connects us with a time or place. Or should it be:

> Who did create this building?

Another example:

> I was near the river.

If I have been near the river,  I can say the above sentence only when I have never been here before and it's my first experience to be here?

Could some please explain me, please.
Is there a possibility if someone can share some links where I can read about this in more detail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple past is for completed actions at a specified time:

- I ate breakfast at 9 am
- This building was built in 1950.

Present perfect has a different usage: it is used when the time that something occurred is unknown or unimportant.  We use Present Perfect for events in the past with an effect now:

- I have eaten breakfast. (When I ate breakfast is unimportant, what is important is that I am not hungry now.)
- The building has been built.

Present perfect is also used with events in the recent past:

- The President has announced his plans for the next month.

BTW: Your question should read,'Who created this building?', although 'create' is not a good verb to use in this context- the 'creator' of a building could be one of many people performing different functions - Was the person who designed it? The person or people who physically constructed it? Or was it the person who paid for it?

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I mean the person who designed that building.

Comment: Why did you write “The building has been built”? Where is the connection with this time?

Comment: But 'Who built this building?' is correct even though there is no specified time. And 'This building was built ...' is a passive construction.

Comment: The building has been built - it is complete and there it is - we can see it, it exists in the present.